# Form is taking data with GET method but not with POST method

Tags: php, forms, http-post

Form is taking data with GET method but not with POST method

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="results">
             <li class="action right"><a class="act" href="loader.php?q=show-songs">
            <label>Name of Song</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Song Name" required="">
            <input type="hidden" name="q" value="add-new-song">

            <label>is this albulm shows in top 20 Songs? <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="t20"></label>

            <label>Select Album of This song</label>
           <select name="album"><option value="41">70s Greatest Love</option><option value="42">coke studio</option><option value="43">krish 3</option><option value="44">Shuddh Desi Romance</option><option value="45">Warning (Original)</option><option value="46">Zanjeer</option><option value="47">Naiyaandi</option>


    </select>
      <li class="action right"><a class="act" href="loader.php?q=new-singer"><img src="../img/add2.png">Add new Singer</a></li>
    <label>Select Singer Name </label>
           <select name="singer"><option value="19">saim</option><option value="20">singer</option> </select>

        <label>Song File</label>
           <input type="file" class="buttonf" name="file1" required="">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>SEO</legend>
            <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Key words and Seo Tags">
            <textarea name="desc1" placeholder="Extra Details About Song"></textarea>

            </fieldset>

           <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add song Details" name="btn">



           </form>
```

The form receiving code is

```
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
        {
            $desc=$_POST['desc1'];
            $tags=$_POST['tags'];
            $feature=0;
            if(isset($_POST['t20']))
            {
            $feature=$_POST['t20'];
            }
            $album_id=$_POST['album'];
            $name=$_POST['name'];

            $singer=$_POST['singer'];

        //  $path="media/$fileName-$date";




        $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

    $t=time();
    $song_path="media/$t-$fileName";

    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../$song_path");

    if (!file_exists("../$song_path")) {
    echo "ERROR: File not uploaded<br /><br />";
    echo "Check folder permissions on the target uploads folder is 0755 or looser.<br /><br />";
    echo "Check that your php.ini settings are set to allow over 2 MB files, they are 2MB by default.";
    exit();
}
else
{


$msg=$this->song_insert($album_id,$singer,$name,$song_path,$feature,$desc,$tags);
echo"<strong><h1 style='color:white; font-family;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:100px;'></strong>$msg</strong></h1>";}

            exit();
        }
```

But it give errors

Notice: Undefined index: desc1 in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 288

Notice: Undefined index: album in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 289

Notice: Undefined index: tags in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 295

Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 296
Notice: Undefined index: file1 in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 281

Notice: Undefined index: album in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 298

Comment: How about doing a `print_r($_POST);` to make sure you're receiving the form inputs correctly?

Comment: @Amal Murali the out put is Array ( )

Comment: `<a class="act" href="loader.php?q=show-songs">` and `<li class="action right"> ... </li>` -- what are these supposed to do? The form should work fine if you remove these.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: desc1 in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 286

Notice: Undefined index: tags in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 287

Notice: Undefined index: album in D:\new\xampp\htdocs\xampp\projects\music\admin\class.php on line 293
still having same issue

Comment: If you send data to form with `method="get"` you need to receive it with `$_GET` in php.
Your `$_POST` Variable is empty so change `method="post"`

Comment: when i use to remove enctype="multipart/form-data" it work fine but file is not uploading

Comment: @ mjb4 i use method="get" and $_GET to test the get mehode but when  i set method="post" and check it with $_POST it is not working

Comment: True in the form it says get. Ok pls tell us where did you put the `print_r` because you should not get any error in the above code!
`if(isset($_POST['btn']))` should prevent this!

Comment: if i use  `! if(isset($_POST['btn']))` it shows nothing means it does not enter in the if scope

i think the real issue is with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`